# Update specific tab on google sheet - Python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have the following code to append a dataframe in to a google sheet that runs everyday.
I had to create 03 more tabs in to this sheet and now, every time I upload the dataframe it goes to another tab and not the one that I need.
I`m using the following code to update the gsheet:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_key("1O1NKT4LRf7F17kRjupUD7peonCwT04BG-l7pbo5-BLU").sheet1
values = df.values.tolist()
sh.append_rows(values)
```

I tried a few things such as

```
sh = gc.open_by_key("1O1NKT4LRf7F17kRjupUD7peonCwT04BG-l7pbo5-BLU").tabname
```

But it didnt work. Is there a way to do that?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sheet1](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.sheet1) will give you the first worksheet in your spreadsheet, if your target sheet is not the first worksheet then you might need to use other methods to access that particular worksheet.

**Best option is to get the worksheet by title** (if you select worksheet using indexes, you need to update your code if ever you re-arranged your tabs. Hence the best option is to select worksheet by its title)

---

### Here are all the options that you can use to [select a worksheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet) using gspread:

Select worksheet by index. Worksheet indexes start from zero:

```
sh = gc.open_by_key("1O1NKT4LRf7F17kRjupUD7peonCwT04BG-xxxxxx")
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
```

Or by title:

```
worksheet = sh.worksheet("January")
```

Or the most common case: Sheet1:

```
worksheet = sh.sheet1
```

To get a list of all worksheets: (check each worksheet in the list based on their [title](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.title))

```
worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply here. I did try by name using the following code:
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_key("1O1NKT4LRf7F17kRjupUD7peonCwT04BG-l7pbo5-BLU")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("test")
values = df.values.tolist()
sh.append_rows(values)

And I got an error saying that AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'append_rows'
Any idea what that could be?

Comment: your variable `sh` pertains to the spreadsheet object. it should be `worksheet.append_rows(values)`